# escape sequence "\u" between 80 ff

Tags: bash, unicode, utf-8, fonts, console

How is it possible to print character with an unicode between **0x80 and 0xFF** by using \u escape sequence in a linux console ?
For example,

> [root@...]# setfont /lib/kbd/consolefonts/cp850-8x16.psfu.gz

First, I set the cp850-8x16.psfu.gz to have the copyright character whose unicode is 0xa9.

> [root@...]# echo -e '\u212b'
>   Å

Output is right but unicode is greater than 0xFF

> [root@...]# echo -e '\u00a9'
>   � 
>   [root@...]# echo -e '\ua9'
>   �

Output is not right

> [root@...]# echo -e '\xC2\xa9'
>   ©

If I convert unicode to utf-8, it works 
Rq : 0xA9=0b**10101001** =>(utf-8)  0b110**00010** 0b10**101001** => 0xC2 0xA9)
Is there a solution to use directly a9 with \u (ie. without doing binary arithmetic to obtain utf-8 code and using \x)?

Comment: Use `printf` always! `printf '\u00a9'`

Comment: @inian. First, please read my question carefully and remove your duplicate. It concerns unicode between 80 and FF. I know how to print unicode (cf. echo -e '\u212b' in my question). Second, printf does not work. (Rq : my bash version is 4.2.46)

Comment: @inian. For information : printf("\u00a9") works in C. In man 1 printf, it is written FORMAT controls the output as in C printf. It is not really the case with \u.

Comment: @people who votes down, please, add a comment to explain.

Comment: You only have one down vote! That might be because they saw your question as off topic for Stack Overflow since it is not about programming (just a guess). [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) seems like a more appropriate home for your question to me.

Comment: @skomisa. I thank you for your answer and I agree with you. I posted this question in stack overflow because at the beginning, it was a programming problem in a bash script and I started to write a conversion for number between 0x80 and 0xFF. But, at the end, it was a bug in bash, so superuser is more appropriate. Nevertheless, I think it is too easy to vote down and worse to mark a question as duplicate when you have enough reputation because you do not have to justify it. Do you know if it is possible to transfer question and answer from stackoverflow to superuser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with bash version 4.4.18 but not with my previous version (4.2.46).
After some checks, it works with bash version 4.3.0 but not in 4.2.53.

Comment: For details  (cf  ChangeLog file in bash src). _lib/sh/strtrans.c
 - ansicstr: use 0x7f as the boundary for characters that translate
   directly from ASCII to unicode (\u and \U escapes) instead of
   UCHAR_MAX, since everything >= 0x80 requires more than one byte.
   Bug and fix from John Kearney <dethrophes@web.de>

builtins/printf.def
 - tescape: ditto for printf \u and \U escape sequences_